# Google "Отзывы клиентов" cb=gapi.loaded_0:82 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

При подключении модуля Google "Отзывы клиентов" вылетает ошибка

Chrome console:

```
cb=gapi.loaded_0:82
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Object._.mf (cb=gapi.loaded_0:82)
    at Fz (cb=gapi.loaded_0:103)
    at cb=gapi.loaded_0:103
```

JS

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script>
window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function () {
    window.gapi.surveyoptin.render({
        merchant_id: 'shop_code',
        order_id: '12345',
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        delivery_country: 'RU',
        estimated_delivery_date: '2018-11-23',
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Оказалось Гугл отзвывы клиентов конфликтуют со своим же собственным гугл менеджером тегов и как сказала поддержка, совместить их нереально. Молодцы. Хорошо работаете.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/308867)

Comment: @Эникейщик Это и есть автор вопроса, более того - это вполне себе ответ. Если не сложно, отпишите, почему вы выбрали вариант "не является ответом" - это какая-то случайная ошибка (ткнул не ту кнопку) или есть какая-то аргументация?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло отключение веб-визора в Яндекс Метрике на странице, на которой установили модуль опроса.